# Creating ClassObjects out of corresponding hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, hierarchy

I have two class trees, which have the same structure. I want to create a new class object of one structure from the type and with the attributes from the corresponding class of the other structure.

Here my classes of my control structure:

```
public class ControlBase
{
    public ControlBase(string name);
    string name;
}
public class ControlA : ControlBase
{
    public ControlA(string name, int val) : base(name);
    int val;
}
public class ControlB : ControlBase
{
    public ControlB(string name, double val) : base(name);
    double val;
}
```

xml dataitem classes:

```
public class XMLBase
{
    string name;
}
public class XMLA : XMLBase
{
     int val;
}
public class XMLB : XMLBase
{
     double val;
}
```

I have a list of objects from my xml structure and my problem is:
How can I create the equivalent list of objects from my control structure.

I know I could do something like this, but I don't think it is a clean solution.

```
foreach (XMLBase xmlItem in xmlList)
{
    if(xmlItem is XMLA)
    {
         XMLA toAdd = (XMLA)xmlItem;
         controlList.Add(new ControlA(toAdd.name, toAdd.val));
    }
    if(xmlItem is XMLB)
    ...
}
```

EDIT: some constraints i forgot

1. I should not touch the XML object because they are generated code
2. I can have multiple value members

Comment: Check bridge and prototype patterns to simplify and reuse your structures. Consider both XMLBase and ControlBase to be implementations of BaseBase :) More info here: http://www.oodesign.com/prototype-pattern.html

Comment: Are the xml classes generated as partial classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. You will keep your hierarchy disconnected from the client and control copying objects in the place where they know how to behave.

```
public abstract class ControlBase
{
    protected ControlBase() { }      

    public ControlBase(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract string DisplayMe();        

    protected string name;
}


public class ControlA : ControlBase
{
    public ControlA() { }

    public ControlA(string name, int val) : base(name) { this.val = val; }

    int val;

    public override string DisplayMe()
    {
        return val.ToString();
    }
}

public class ControlB : ControlBase
{
    public ControlB(string name, double val) : base(name) { this.val = val; }

    double val;

    public override string DisplayMe()
    {
        return val.ToString();
    } 
}



public abstract class XMLBase
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public abstract ControlBase ToControl();

}

public class XMLA : XMLBase
{
    public override ControlBase ToControl()
    {
        return new ControlA(Name, Val);
    }

    public int Val {get; set;}
}

public class XMLB : XMLBase
{       
    public override ControlBase ToControl()
    {
        return new ControlB(Name, Val);
    }

    public double Val {get; set;}
}


public class Client
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        IList<XMLBase> xmlList = new List<XMLBase>();

        xmlList.Add(new XMLA() { Name = "minion1", Val = 1 });
        xmlList.Add(new XMLB() { Name = "minion2", Val = 1.232323 });

        IList<ControlBase> controls = new List<ControlBase>();
        foreach (var xmlItem in xmlList)
        {
            var ctrl = xmlItem.ToControl();
            controls.Add(ctrl);
        }


        foreach (ControlBase ctrlBase in controls)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(ctrlBase.DisplayMe());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your idea seems intuitional to me. However I have constraints which disallows me to use this approach. I edited my post.

1. I should not touch the XML object because they are generated code
2. I can have multiple value members (but this would work with the .ToControl method)

Comment: for the first one: try extension methods or partial classes. For the second - I don't see such limitation, can you be more specific?

Comment: thanks both suggestions from you work and I think they scale well. for the second it does not really matter with your solution so I will skip this part. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for a solution with generics (just a fast sample, the code is not compiled, just for the idea):

```
public void <T,T2,T3> MYGenericFunction(IEnumerable<T> xmlList)
    where T: XMLBase<T3>
          T2: new, ControlBase<T3>
{
    foreach (T xmlItem in xmlList)
    {
        T2 item = new T2();
        item.Name = toAdd.name;
        item.Val = toAdd.val;
        controlList.Add(T2);
    }
}

public class<T> ControlBase
{
    public ControlBase();
    public string Name;
    public T Val;
}


public class<T> XMLBase
{
    public string name;
    public T val;
}
```

Comment: With that approach, the control on how to copy still is on the client side so it will be hard to extend. There is a way to keep client small and without knowledge of hierarchy structure when you move copying/cloning/casting to types themselves. Not sure what is the problem to solve with that Control hierarchy and has client really have to know every single class in the hierarchy. If there will be more classes in hierarchy coming generics on the client side will not help you much.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the  the XML classes then why not add a virtual methold:

```
public virtal ControlBase ToControl();
```

and then have each XML class implement it:

```
public class XMLBase
{
    string name;

    public virtual ControlBase ToControl()
    {
       return new ControlBase(name);
    }
}
public class XMLA : XMLBase
{
    int val;

    public override ControlBase ToControl()
    {
       return new ControlA(name, val);
    }
}
public class XMLB : XMLBase
{
    double val;

    public override ControlBase ToControl()
    {
       return new ControlB(name, val);
    }
}
```

Now your loop looks like this:

```
foreach (XMLBase xmlItem in xmlList)
{
  var control = xmlItem.ToControl();
  controlList.Add(control);
}
```

This has the advantage that it puts the creation the the `Control` right next to the thing that know how to create it.

If you're able to make `XMLBase` abstract then this would be better, as it will allow you to make `ToControl` abstract as well. This way derived class will be forced to implement it, rather than having to remember to override it.